# Computations and physical processes

Tags: quantum-computer, computer

Can computation be accomplished using any physical process? For simplicity let me restrict myself to the computation of performing addition. I am aware that mechanical calculators just use Newtonian mechanics to perform computation. As far as I can see, it seems that it is possible to perform computation using any physical setup: Be it mechanical gears, electromagnetic fields, or unitary operations on quantum states. All that we seem to require is the ability to represent our numbers in terms of physical states and have a differential equation governing the evolution of those states(so that differing initial conditions lead to differing final states).
Are there any counter examples for this observation? What are the requirements that a physical system must satisfy so that it is capable of performing addition(or computation in general)?

Answer (score 0):

We differentiate between *qualitative* (also called categorical, non-numerical) and *quantitative* (also called numerical) variables. E.g. the colour of an object is usually assumed to be a quantitative variable. If we add a red object and a green object, we usually do not obtain a single object of a different colour.

Usually, physics is concerned with quantitative descriptions. I believe that Galileo Galileis is responsible for this, because he argued that the measurement is the key ingredient to build knowledge. Hence, descriptions/phenomena which are not measurable are usually considered to be meta-physical.

Comment: I think the ability of physical systems to function as a computer is not metaphysical and is quantifiable too.